# Run Completable Future in parallel for an large list with same method

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have list contains large amount of data ( e,g 50 k approx). I need to perform some operation on each list item and then have to map the result from processing to java object to write into the csv.  so far the sequential code for this is working fine for me.

```
list.stream().map(listItem->
           service.methodA(listItem)
                    .map(result ->mapToBean(result, listItem))
    ).flatMap(Optional::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This operation is slow takes around 4 hr for 2k data processing. So I decided to speedup this by Aysnc Processing using completable future library.( I'm new to Completable future) Here is the code I written for parallel processing.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfCores-1);
Lists.partition(list, 500).stream()
                .map(item-> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> executeListPart (item),service))
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But when I run this code, I observed that thread 1 processing the one part of list then wait for it to complete and then Thread2 start processing another part and so on. Hence it seems to execute sequentially (of-course in different thread) hence here no gain for me.  I want to execute the each partition in parallel and finally collect the result of each thread and combine at the last. Can someone let help me to achieve this.

Comment: Have you started by using the much simpler parallel streams instead of completable futures?

Comment: this was my first thought but using parrelStream leads me to out of memory on large dataset. So I moved to Completable future, referring  link

https://roytuts.com/difference-between-parallel-stream-and-completablefuture-in-java/#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20advantages%20of,based%20on%20your%20application%20requirements.&text=Now%20it%20took%20just%2010,of%20tasks%20with%2010%20threads.

Comment: Now if only the stream API had an easy way to do things in parallel... Have you tried `stream().parallel()` instead of shoehorning the completable future API in there. I also doubt the bulk of the processing is in the Java stuff but more or less in the writing (or reading of the whole list). Having 50k things in memory probably isn't the smart way of doing things (especially if those are also read from a database before hand).

Comment: These list are not read from the database.  This is all read from an csv file and input is expected to be large of-course. I guess parralelStream () and stream().parralel() are the same things right? There is no control of defining your own thread pool hence  I tried experimenting with CompetableFuture.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your tasks are being executed sequentially is because you do `.map(CompletableFuture::join)` during the pipeline execution and what actually happens is that the execution will wait for the `CompletableFuture` to join before moving with the next item in the `forEach`. You would need to remove that particular map operation from your stream.

To wait for the all the task termination, there are a couple of ways to do it. One is to call `shutdown()` on your ExecutorService and then `awaitTermination(TIMEOUT)`. However this is not efficient if you are going to use that same ExecutorService again during your app lifecycle.

Another, would be to do something like the following:

```java
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfCores-1);
var completableFutureList = Lists.partition(list, 500).stream()
                .map(item-> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> executeListPart (item),service)).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

...and then:

```java
completableFutureList.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```

Happy hacking! =)

Comment: I tried this way. but no luck

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava If this (useful looking) answer doesn't help then maybe you are looking in wrong place. Is `executeListPart (item)` designed to work in different threads?  check the code: perhaps it synchronises due to contention on some shared resources / files / database.  Check noOfCores is greater than 2.  Running N copies of same task does not always speed things up.

Comment: Hey @AnuragSrivastava can you provide more details as to what happens when you try my approach? If you figured it out how to do the code using my answer then I would appreciate it if you marked it as correct!